# self.view / super.view

Tags: objective-c, subview, self, super, superview

what's the difference between

```
[self.view addSubview:view1];
```

and

```
[super.view addSubview:view1];
```

Thank You!!

Franhu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you've overridden the `-view` method, there is no practical difference. From a semantic difference, though, saying `super.view` is an express attempt to avoid invoking a method named `-view` defined in the current class. Unless you want to express that meaning, you should stay away from the `super.whatever` construct.

Answer (score 0):

Since view is a property, there isn't really much difference when it comes down to it.

Personally I think the self.view is more readable and is the more commonly used idiom as far as I know.